# How to slide a label to right when touched?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, slider, uilabel

In my app I created a UiLabel. I have to move the label to right depending upon touch gesture, like Slide out menu. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UITapGestureRecognizer :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

[label addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

And then use UIViewAnimation in your method:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {


     CGRect frame = label.frame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

     frame.origin.x += 100; // slide right
    label.frame = frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I did it using UISwipeGestureRecognizer,but I have to move the label on touch 1:1,mean to say that as soon as i touch and move my touch the label (left/right)should also move along with my touch

Comment: Maybe should you use `touchBegan:` and `touchMoved:` if you wanna move the UILabel with your finger. Indded, the `touchMoved:`method will be called until you stop swiping the UILabel, and you also can get the exact coordinate of the touch and assigning them as the UILabel's frame. Also you can take a look at: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/11/draggable-buttons-labels/ but i'm not sure this is the best way to proceed.

Comment: Can I restrict the label to a specific area so that my label should be able to move within a specific area.

Comment: You can make a condition on coordinate.x or .y to restrict the translation in a specific area. Example: `if(label.frame.origin.x > 150) return; `

Answer (score 0):

Suppose UILabel outlet name is testing .

```
// set up geture as follows in view did load
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelDidSwiped:)];
[swipeGesture setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[testing addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];

swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelDidSwiped:)];
[swipeGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

[testing addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];

-(void)labelDidSwiped:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
switch (gesture.direction) {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
        // you can change the frame of label in here depending on your requirement
        DLog(@"left swipe");
        break;
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
// you can change the frame of label in here depending on your requirement
        break;
    default:
        break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supply positions using CGPointMake function

```
label.position = CGPointMake (newX, newY);
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration = <duration>;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
animation.fromValue = CGPointMake (oldX, oldY);
animation.toValue = CGPointMake (newX, newY);
[label addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```